# Adobe Livecycle Balnks spaces when form hidden

Tags: livecycle-designer

```
I have used if (this.rawValue == "0") {
  this.resolveNode("Subform1").presence = "hidden";
}
```

in adobe livcycle. It creates a blank space for the element. Is there a function to collapse the section instead of compressing it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the subform that contains "Subform1" should have flow layout with height set to "adjust to content", so that when you hide "Subform1" the container will collapse.

Comment: if there are many pages and if the entire page to be hidden and the bottom page has to go up.

Comment: same concept. you need to use flow layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many people struggling with the empty space of hidden fields in Adobe Form.
So to resolve this issue you have to make sure following points,

1. Your subform should have content as Flowed.
2. Flow direction does not matter.
3. If you are using event with scripts to hide the field, make sure correct format is used, i.e. most of the time it should be Language = FormCalc and RunAt = Client.
   This is the part where most of the mistakes are done.

Hope it will resolve your issue of Empty space for hidden fields in Adobe Form.